# Why did Google invalidate all OAuth2 access tokens today?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

**What happened to your OAuth2/token servers today around 7am PST?**
URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Token refreshing failed (credential.refreshToken()==false) for all our Google users resulting in losing access tokens and connectivity for hundreds of our clients!

Then for a while our users could not re-authorize as Google was returning 503 Unavailable and CAPTURE in response to the following API call:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow gacf =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                new JacksonFactory(), appId,
                appSecret, scopes).build();
tokenResponse = gacf.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(<callback_url>).execute();
```

com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable

> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot.

After a while everything started working again only now we have hundreds of clients for whom our service stopped working because there is no valid OAuth2 access tokens anymore.

Can you please explain what Google did earlier today and how it managed to invalidate all the tokens? How can we find out what "unusual traffic" it detected?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You on AppEngine??

if so, maybe it's this...

SUMMARY:

On Thursday 5 March 2015, for a duration of 84 minutes, Google App Engine applications that accessed some Google APIs over HTTP experienced elevated error rates. We apologize for any impact this incident had on your service or application, and have made immediate changes to prevent this issue from recurring.

DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF IMPACT:

On Thursday 5 January, from 07:04 AM to 08:28 AM, some Google App Engine applications making calls to other Google APIs via HTTP experienced elevated error rates. During the incident, the global error rate for all API calls remained under 1%, and in total, the outage affected 2% of applications that were active during the incident.  The effect on those applications was significant: requests to issue OAuth tokens experienced an error rate of over 85%. In addition, the HTTP APIs to googleapis.com/storage and googleapis.com/gmail received error rates between 50% and 60%. Other googleapis.com endpoints were affected with error rates of 10% to 20%.

ROOT CAUSE:

A component in Google’s shared HTTP load balancing fabric experienced a non-malicious increase in traffic, exceeding its provisioned capacity. This triggered an automatic DoS protection which shunted a portion of the incoming traffic to a CAPTCHA.  The unexpected response caused some clients to issue automated retries, exacerbating the problem.

REMEDIATION AND PREVENTION:

Google Engineers were alerted to the issue by automated monitoring at 07:02, as the load balancing system detected excess traffic and attempted to automatically mitigate it. At 07:46, Google Engineers enabled standby load balancing capacity to rectify the issue. From 08:15 to 08:40, Google Engineers continued to provision additional resources in the load balancing fabric in order to serve the increased traffic. During this period, at 08:28, Google engineers determined that sufficient capacity was in place to serve both regular and retry traffic, and instructed the load balancing system to cease mitigation and resume normal traffic serving.  This action marked the end of the event.

To prevent this issue from recurring, Google engineers are comprehensively re-examining the affected load balancing fabric to ensure it is and remains correctly provisioned.  Additionally, Google engineers are improving monitoring rules to provide an early warning of capacity shortfall. Finally, Google engineers are examining the services that depend on this load balancing system, and will move some services to a separate pool of more easily scalable load balancers where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Must be related to this.